# Independence from a linear combination of dependent random variables

Tags: random-variables, independence, bivariate-distributions

Let $W = aX + bY$, where $(X,Y)$ are jointly normal random variables (bivariate).
Also let $E[X] = E[Y] = 0$; so we know $E[W] = 0$, as well.
Furthermore, we assume $Var(X) = 4$ and $Var(Y) = 25$, and $Cor(X,Y) = 0.3$ (which implies that $Cov(X,Y) = 3$).

Find values for $a$ and $b$ so that $W$ and $X$ are independent and $Var(W) > 0$.

The part I get stuck on is that $Cor(W,X) = 0$ does not necessarily mean that the variables $W$ and $X$ are independent, just that they do not correlate.

The first equation for my system of equations is $4a + 3b = 0$.

My next step was to define $W$ and $X$ as independent and Let $Y = (1/b)W - (a/b)X = cW + dX$.

This gives an equation for $Var(Y) = 25 = c^2Var(W) + 4d^2$, which resolves to:

$Var(W) = 25b^2 - 4a^2$.

Choosing $a = -3$ and $b = 4$ works just fine for both of these equations, but my equation for $Var(W)$ will always be satisfied (greater than 0) so long as $a$ and $b$ satisfy $4a + 3b = 0$.  So it isn't helping to limit my choices of $a$ and $b$ at all!

Please help!  I have no idea how to ensure that W and X are independent if $W = aX + bY$ besides making $a = b = 0$, and this gives a $Var(W) = 0$...

Answer (score 1):

you are almost done. You just need the following result, it is also stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent):

> If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normally distributed then $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

But be careful: it is important that the joint distribution is normal. If $X$ has a normal distribution and $Y$ has a normal distribution but the joint distribution is not normal, then the above result does **not** hold. There is also an example which illustrates this if you follow the link above.
So $a=-3$ and $b=4$ is a perfect solution.
You just have to argue why the joint normal distribution of $X$ and $Y$ implies the joint normal distribution of $X$ and $W$.